# Mac El Capitan unable to get ctrl + arrowkey value

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

hi I'm trying to get ctrl + left_arrow and ctrl + right_arrow values in order to make a binding in some program, but when I do, in zsh, ^V + these combination I get nothing. 
How can I get those values?

Answer (score 0):

Those key combinations are configured, by default, to switch desktop spaces. This can be configured in System Preferences > Keyboard pane > Shortcuts tab > Mission Control in the left table > Move left/right a space.

So, the system is swallowing the event before apps get a chance to see them. That makes these key combinations a poor choice for your program's binding.

Comment: Perhaps that is true for a new install (I cannot verify that), but is not the case on my machine: there is a binding, but not enabled.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, do you have the same symptom as the questioner (can't receive Control-left/right-arrow in programs)? Then you've probably reassigned those key combinations to another function. Search through the other shortcuts on that tab to see if you can find it. If you don't have the symptom, then disabling those shortcuts is probably why.